# Использование объекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
# ОКНО СОЗДАНИЯ НОВОГО ПЕРСОНАЖА
class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
# События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
        self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
# Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)


# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
    def NewPersonName(self, name):
        self.name = name
        global checkname
        checkname = self.name    

# ФУНКЦИЯ Создания нового персонажа
    def MakeNewPerson(self):
        import pathlib
        # AGE 1
        if timeedit == 1:
            # Проверяем Заполнение полей
            if not self.name:
                self.ui.result.setText("Введите имя Исторической Личности")
```

Немножко не понимаю концепцию ООП. Мне надо из функции `NewPersonName` перенести объект `self.name` в функцию `MakeNewPerson` чтобы сработала проверка.

Comment: публикуйте пожалуйста минимально-полный код для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: @S.Nick Изменил вопрос

Comment: @S.Nick на timeedit не обращайте внимания он в другом месте задаётся

Comment: не обращать внимание - не получается :)  Ui_newperson - ? timeedit - ? Я не совсем понял вопрос, у вас методы `NewPersonName` и `MakeNewPerson` принадлежат одному `class NewPerson`. Объявите `self.name = ""` в конструкторе и пользуйтесь во всех методах класса. А про существование оператора `global` я вам рекомендую забыть .